# (Zabbix internals) How Zabbix checks for snmp_available hosts status?

Tags: snmp, zabbix, availability

Our Zabbix frontend shows SNMP availability status of several hosts that seems to be monitored well as "unknown", Zabbix API also returns snmp_available=0, because zabbix_proxy set "unknown status" of SNMP agent availability for these hosts.

But I can see actual latest data collected from those hosts with SNMP and I'm in doubt: how to debug that situation, how Zabbix server or Zabbix proxy makes a decision that some hosts' SNMP agent status is unknown? What SNMP checks does it performs to know, whether host is available by SNMP or no? Where [in source codes of Zabbix] can I look for real internal implementation of these checks? I was trying to search in checks_internal.c, but no luck (and "item" parameter of get_value_internal function written by Alexei Vladishev seems to be described in a very unclear manner: "item - item we are interested in").

So... how to do the same checks as Zabbix does when investigating whether host is available or not - by hand?

Comment: How many SNMP interfaces does that host have?

Comment: Only one interface

Comment: What item types do those hosts have? Which Zabbix version?

Answer (score 0):

I think I´ve found the solution.
The internal check for SNMP availability must be part of some template which contains some SNMP checks. And when these SNMP checks starts to obtain data, then the internal check starts works.